# Update/Attach multiple rectangles in one method?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I need to have two rectangles that are elements of an array called NPCrectangle move to bodies that are elements of an array that is called NPCbody. This is what I am doing:

```
try {
        if ((NPCrectangle.size() > 0) && (NPCbody.size() > 0)) {
            System.out.println("NPCrectangle size is "+NPCrectangle.size());

                System.out.println("For statement 1 passed for NPCrectangle ");
                for (int j = 0; j < NPCrectangle.size(); j++) {

                    NPCrectangle.get(j).setX(NPCbody.get(j).getPosition().x*32);
                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, vbom);
                    rectangle.setX(NPCbody.get(j).getPosition().x*32);
                    rectangle.setY(NPCbody.get(j).getPosition().y*32);
                    attachChild(rectangle);
                    System.out.println("RECTANGLE ATTACHED FOR NPC"+j);


                }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Which updates them, but since it creates a new rectangles each time the old one is never detached. I need to be able to have every rectangle element of array NPCrectangle move to its respective NPC element in NPCarray. How can I do this?

Comment: Try making one method for creating them and one for updating them. This all-in-one approach is gonna get messy.

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon I was thinking about doing that, having one for loop and creating one for every element, but how would I go about naming them based on elements?

Comment: Try extending your NPCBody class to include a reference to a rectangle. Then as you go through the NPC array, you can use the rectangle reference. If the reference is null, make a new one  and assign the new reference to the NPCBody.